# How do I print value from hashmap json object

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I am learning about jsonobject in java. I want to print value from json object. I am reading from URL and the storing into hashmap. but now I do I print particulate value like term and type.

I WANT TO PRINT TERM AND TYPE FROM HASHMAP WHICH I AM CREATING.
Here is my code
Here is my response from URL
{
    "neighborhoods": {
        "label": "abc",
        "value": []
    },
    "communities": {
        "label": "xyz",
        "value": {
            "83": {
                "label": "San Francisco Bay Area, California 94538",
                "value": 83,
                "type": "community",
                "term": "abc"
            },
            "94": {
                "label": "San Francisco Bay Area, California 94538",
                "value": 94,
                "type": "community",
                "term": "II"
            }
        }
    }
}

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
  String url = "Removing URL and added json response which getting above the code";
      URL obj = new URL(url);
      HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
      int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
      System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
      System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
      BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
      String inputLine;
      StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
       while ((inputLine = in.readL***strong text***ine()) != null) {
         response.append(inputLine);
       } in .close();
       //print in String
        System.out.println(response.toString());
       JSONObject myresponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
       System.out.println(myresponse);

       JSONObject neighborhoods_object = new JSONObject(myresponse.getJSONObject("neighborhoods").toString());
       System.out.println("\n\nNeighborhoods Objects -" + neighborhoods_object);

       JSONObject communities_object = new JSONObject(myresponse.getJSONObject("communities").toString());
       System.out.println("\nCommunities Objects -" + communities_object);
       System.out.println("Text from Label " + communities_object.getString("label"));

       JSONObject value_object1 = new JSONObject(communities_object.getJSONObject("value").toString());
       System.out.println("\nCommunities Objects and within that Value Object-" + value_object1);

       Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       System.out.println("Length " + value_object1.length());

       Iterator<String> keysItr = value_object1.keys();
       while(keysItr.hasNext()) {
            String key = keysItr.next();
            Object value = value_object1.get(key);
            result.put(key, value);
       }

       for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : result.entrySet())
       {
           System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
    //   JSONObject neighborhoods_object2 = new JSONObject(value_object1.getJSONObject("83").toString());

    //   System.out.println("\n\nNeighborhoods Objects 2-" + neighborhoods_object2);
    //
    //   JSONObject neighborhoods_object3 = new JSONObject(value_object1.getJSONObject("83").toString());
    //   System.out.println("Value of Label-" + neighborhoods_object3.getString("label"));
    //   System.out.println("Value of -" + neighborhoods_object3.getInt("value"));
    //   System.out.println("Type -" + neighborhoods_object3.getString("type"));
    //   System.out.println("Short Term-" + neighborhoods_object3.getString("term"));
       }


      } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
```

## }

{
    "neighborhoods": {
        "label": "Neighborhoods",
        "value": []
    },
    "communities": {
        "label": "Communities",
        "value": {
            "83": {
                "label": "Mission Peaks - San Francisco Bay Area, California 94538",
                "value": 83,
                "type": "community",
                "term": "Mission Peaks"
            },
            "94": {
                "label": "Mission Peaks II - San Francisco Bay Area, California 94538",
                "value": 84,
                "type": "community",
                "term": "Mission Peaks II"
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: What are term and type?  I don't see anything by that name in your code.

Comment: That is in value_object1 JSONObject. So I am creating hashmap with key and object and from that I want to print.

Comment: That's not going to be possible so long as your map is of type `<String, Object>`.  You need to let the compiler know what the data looks like if you want to be able to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be enough for you to get the details out of your json object

```
urlConnection.connect();
is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(line + "\n");
}
is.close();
json = sb.toString();
jObj = new JSONObject(json);
```

After that just use

```
jObj.getString("key");
```

or any type of variable you want

Comment: I am able print but there is nested json object is there. here is the response. I removed URL

Comment: I believe it is jsonArray. try fetching each one of the keys as ' jsonObject.getJSONArray("key") ' and it will help you get it

Comment: But anyway if it is a nested json object you can just do ' jsonObject.getJSONObject("key") '